# CakePHP 2.4 Basic HTTP Authentication popup loop

Tags: php, cakephp, restful-authentication, basic-authentication

I am currently trying to setup a RESTful webservice /w a **Basic HTTP Authentication**, and a **Form authentication for web users**. (Basic is for Mobile clients).

Cake is using Joomla password hashing through a custom passwordHasher implementation. In form mode, there is no problem, all works like a charm. In Basic Auth mode, the popup window that's asking for credentials is looping : no matter the credentials I give, the popup always ask me credentials. When I click on cancel button, this redirects me on a 401 Unauthorized status (normal behavior here)

Here's my code :

**Controller/AppController.php**

```
<?php
class AppController extends Controller
{
    public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'users',
                'action' => 'getFields'
            ),
            'authenticate' => array(
                'Form' => array(
                    'passwordHasher' => array('className' => 'Joomla')
                )
            )
        ),
        'RequestHandler'
    );

    public function beforeFilter()
    {
        // Change the authentication if using REST
        if($this->params['ext'] == 'json' || $this->params['ext'] == 'xml')
        {
            $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
                'Basic' => array(
                    'passwordHasher' => array('className' => 'Joomla')
                )
            );
            // Ensure AuthComponent doesn’t try to read user info from session.
            AuthComponent::$sessionKey = false;
        }

        $this->Auth->allow('index', 'view');

    }

}
```

**Controller/UsersController.php**

```
class UsersController extends AppController
{

    function beforeFilter()
    {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('add', 'logout');
    }

    public function login()
    {
        if($this->request->is('post'))
        {
            $usernameForm = $this->request->data['User']['username'];
            $passwordForm = $this->request->data['User']['password'];

            $this->request->data['User']['password'] = $passwordForm . ':' . $this->User->getUserSalt($usernameForm);

            if($this->Auth->login())
            {
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash("Login et/ou mot de passe invalides !");
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller/Components/JoomlaPasswordHasher.php**

```
<?php

App::uses('AbstractPasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');

class JoomlaPasswordHasher extends AbstractPasswordHasher
{
    public function hash($password)
    {
        return $this->_joomlaEncryption($password);
    }

    public function check($password, $hashedPassword)
    {
        return ($this->_joomlaEncryption($password) === $hashedPassword);
    }

    private function _joomlaEncryption($password)
    {
        $password = explode(':', $password);
        $salt = $password[1];

        // On hash selon la methode joomla et on compare
        $hashed = md5($password[0].$salt) . ':' . $salt;
        return $hashed;
    }

}
```

I really don't understand this problem when it works in Form authentication...
Thanks for your help.

**UPDATE 1 : OK. I found the problem source : the server configuration. It's a CGI/FastCGI server.
I tried this in my webroot .htaccess, but nothing changed. Any ideas ?**

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization},QSA,L]
```

Comment: did you tried editing .htaccess files in your app and root folder or just edited webroot .htaccess ?